# Sending to a distribution list using Mail.App in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been trying to send to a distribution list(e.g department.name@company.com) but the Google Script is not reading the email address. I am currently using a for-loop to just get the listed email from a column but is there a way to do this without the loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a minimal reproducible example with code, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Include an image of your sheet?